# windows 8 editable combobox

Tags: windows-8

In windows 8 xaml I wanted to add a editable combobox

for example : I want the following items to be in the combobox : item1, item2 and

When user clicks  the combo becomes and the user can enter the text in place

Is this possible?

I have explored isReadOnly isEditable properites but they seem to be readonly properties

Answer (score 0):

When user click in ComboBox You can handle click event and replace ComboBox with TextBox.

Or check this property: [ComboBox.IsEditable Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Norbert But in windows 8 recent release.. I get an error saying.. this is readonly property and can't be set.. I tried using readonly of the combo box property as well